# Travelling from Botswana to China via Hong Kong

Tags: transit-visas, hong-kong

I have a visa for China and will be travelling from Botswana, via South Africa, through Hong Kong to mainland China.  Do I need a transit visa for Hong Kong to transit to mainland China? I will be using the same route when coming back too.

EDIT: I am a Botswana national.

Comment: What is your nationality? Botswana?

Comment: As @jpatokal mentioned, please clarify your nationality as the answer depended on it. Botswana nationals does not require a transit visa as per [Hong Kong Immigration Department's website](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html), but a transit visa may be required for national of other countries.

Comment: Yes  my nationality is Botswana

Answer (score 1):

It seems from the [Visit Visa / Entry Permit Requirements for the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html) that citizens of Botswana are entitled to a 90-day visa free visit. So if you have time, you may even sight-see outside the airport if you want to.

Comment: For completeness, "have time" here means a hell lot of time, in the order of 4+ hours. See this [slightly outdated yet still applicable discussion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44664/what-can-i-do-in-hong-kong-with-a-three-hour-layover) here.

Comment: Yes, good point. Enough time means a few hours to spare after accounting for the immigration exit and reentry. I just assumed OP would know that.